# How to do condition based query in Eloquent ORM, Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get public timeline where I can access all public posts and get friends all posts (i.e may it be public or private). How can I manage it in one condition where I can get all public posts of everyone and private posts of friends. The code below is working for only public videos.

```
$friends = json_decode($this->friend->where('user', $this->currentUser->id)->first()->list, true);
$blockedUserArray = $this->getBlockedList();
$friends[] = $this->currentUser->id;
$videos = $this->video
        ->withCount('videoComment', 'videoLike')
        ->where('privacy', 'EVERYONE')
        ->orWhereIn('user', $friends)
        ->whereNotIn('user', $blockedUserArray)
        ->latest()
        ->paginate($this->videoPaginate);
```

I can do it with two queries, but it will effect in pagination. Is there any way to do it in a single query?

Comment: short answer, yes, long answer, it depends :)

Comment: If the relationships makes sense it can be achieved. But you need to post a lot more data for that if you want people to look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must group these two query

```
->where('privacy', 'EVERYONE')
->orWhereIn('user', $friends)
```

to

```
->where($query, function($query) use ($friends) {
    $query->where('privacy', 'EVERYONE')
          ->orWhereIn('user', $friends);
})
```

Check the document [Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping)

Comment: My above query did work, but due to less data, I got confused. And thanks for the parameter grouping, its kinda cool way for conditional queries